# Request is not authorized to perform this operation (403 unauthorized) . Azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice, blobstorage

We have multiple backend APIs hosted on Microsoft Azure web app under same app service plan. All APIs have same outbound ip's, and all these APIs enabled access restriction, these APIs only accessible within the  API gateway. We have blob storage, we have also enable restriction on it  (Networking Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses  Firewall, added all APIs ip's on it), Now when APIs going to fetch some image from blob it throw following error,

Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:0bc5827d-c01e-0030-382f-929e61000000
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
Content:

`AuthorizationFailure`This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

RequestId:0bc5827d-c01e-0030-382f-929e61000000
Time:2023-05-29T13:11:56.0013545Z

Note:Both APIs and blob are not using vNet, and both are on same resource group and using the same Identity
but when we remove network restriction on storage account it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled [VNET integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration) on your WebApp and activated the [service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) for the storage account on your VNET?

Comment: no we are not using VNET and service endpoint

Comment: How do you manage network restrictions?

Comment: we are using access restriction in app service and allow only the required ip's. and same for storage accountonly the required ip's are allowed All the required ip's are added and verified

Comment: How did you apply IP restriction from the Web application? Have you taken a look at VNET integration and the VNET service endpoint?

Comment: I have applied through Access restriction in Networking of app service. I have gone through we want it do it with VNET / service endpoint

Comment: And so is it working now?

Comment: If restriction is enabled it works fine as I ad restrictions it fails ...

Comment: Could you explain your current architecture again? I don't understand your changes.

Comment: 1) I have my app service and storage account in azure . My app service communicate with that  storage account. When I add app service and storage account to same VNET and apply Nsg with allow all outbound ip's it  still gives me 403 forbidden to access storage 

2) I attach my app service with VNET and attach Nsg with that VNET . added rules to allow specified ip's. When call app service from specified ip's it gives 403 forbidden. 

I want to enable restriction by adding rules in Nsg and disable access restriction from app service

Comment: How did you "add" the storage account to the VNET?

Have you enabled the service endpoint for storage account on your VNET? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview